# limiting the URL output from newspaper

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I'm using newspaper3 to extract URLs from news.google, but the problem is I keep getting all the URLs (I've disabled memoize because I need the full list). I would like to only print the top 5 links or 5 random links doesn't really matter. 
I've tried setting a max, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```python
import newspaper

news = newspaper.build('https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?oc=3&ceid=US:en', memoize_articles=False)

for article in news.articles:
    print(article.url)
```

Comment: If you want to print the first five and your `news.articles` is an iterable (like a list or tuple) you could probably do `for article in news.articles[:5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet should be exactly what you want. It doesn't use a newspaper function but rather random to select a certain number of urls. The output from newspaper isn't a list therefore it has to be converted into a list using the append function. Enjoy!

```html
import newspaper

business_news = newspaper.build('https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqJggKIiBDQkFTRWdvSUwyMHZNRGx6TVdZU0FtVnVHZ0pWVXlnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen', language='en', memoize_articles = False)

myList = []
for article in business_news.articles:
    myList.append(str(article.url))
print(myList) #not necessary just for display purposes

import random

aselect = myList
randarticles = random.sample(aselect, 5)

print(randarticles)
```